# Testing uninitialized spring security and rest controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

If I make a spring-boot web based rest API and just add the `spring-boot-starter-security` jar the application will initialize like so:

```
2023-10-27T15:06:17.219-04:00  WARN 19172 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: db6773b8-f34d-4675-b9bd-c6921cf8b79e

This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.

2023-10-27T15:06:17.282-04:00  INFO 19172 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2023-10-27T15:06:17.302-04:00  INFO 19172 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@773cc551, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5cbaafbd, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@772589ed, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2ef3efcc, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@4f0f56f5, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@2a045e85, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3f910f36, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@7ffb0bb4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@2bb118ae, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@6edb093f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@11e75942, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@c040c8d, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4917992b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@7f5c4ff8, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@640028f2, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@c6653e]
```

I have not put any sort of configuration in place for the security framework. Is it possible to test easily with postman at this point?

Comment: it is documented here in the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/getting-started.html#servlet-hello-starting

Comment: @Toerktumlare Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as soon as spring security is on the classpath, when you start your application it will load in the default setup. Spring is what is called *secure by default* which means it will lock down everything and you have to gradually configure it to unlock things.

you can directly query an endpoint using curl and get a *401 UNAUTHORIZED* back

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:8080/some/path
HTTP/1.1 401
```

in your logs when you start up you will find a autogenerated password that is used for the default configurated *basic authentication*.

You can query again using `user` and the autogenerated password using the `-u` flag in curl

```
$ curl -i -u user:8e557245-73e2-4286-969a-ff57fe326336 http://localhost:8080/some/path
HTTP/1.1 404
```

which returns a 404 since we havn't setup an endpoint yet.